# Comparing a Boolean object to a boolean primitive

Tags: java, boolean

What will be the output of this code? Please explain how the Autoboxing or unboxing id done here.

```
class MyBoolean
{
    Boolean[] bool = new Boolean[5];

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      new MyBoolean().myMethod();
    }

    public void myMethod()
    {
      if(bool[1]==true)
      {
        System.out.println("It's true");
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.println("It's false");
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you run it and find out?

Comment: I need to know what is happening internally in this comparison:

Comment: I'm serious; run it, and you will get your answer.

Answer (score 6):

The code fails with a `NullPointerException` because `bool[1]` contains `null`. According to the [Java Language Specification, Section 5.1.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8), the unboxing of a `Boolean` is done by calling [`booleanValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#booleanValue%28%29) on the `Boolean` reference. Since in this case, the reference is `null`, you get an NPE.

In a comment on another answer, you wrote:

> The reason to ask this question is to understand if we get the NPE via AutoUnBoxing or via AutoBoxing. In my understanding its due to AutoBoxing.

It's due to *unboxing* (extracting a primitive from a reference type), not boxing (wrapping a primative in a reference type). Specifically, from [JLS Section 15.21.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.2) (*Boolean Equality Operators `==` and `!=`*):

> If one of the operands is of type `Boolean`, it is subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).

Answer (score 4):

Run fails: bool[1] is null and comparison throw NullPointerException.

Comment: -1: the '==' operator cannot cause the NullPointerException.

Comment: But Java try to convert bool[1] to a Boolean object to eval comparison. You got a NullPointerException.

Comment: @dash1e: *"But Java try to convert bool[1] to a Boolean object"* No, the runtime tries to convert the `Boolean` in `bool[1]` to a `boolean` *primitive* (lower case). It's *that* conversion that causes the NPE, because there's no `Boolean` in `bool[1]` at all.

Comment: You are right, it is already a Boolean, Java try to convert in boolean, I wrote quickly when I see downvotes.

Comment: It is a tricky question and its not on my homework :). The reason to ask this question is to understand if we get the NPE via AutoUnBoxing or via AutoBoxing. In my understanding its due to AutoBoxing.

Explanation. bool is an array of Boolean objects, but since it is not initialized all the elements in the array are "null". Remember "null" is not an object. Now when we try to access the elements of the bool array using bool[1] at that point the compiler try to Autobox nulls to Boolean objects and then we get NPE.

Comment: @Vibhor: Not autoboxing, autoUNboxing. See my answer for references.